# How to post data to a word press site in case of a mobile app

Tags: php, user-access, json

I have a site made with word press. I came across a requirement where a developer tries to log in from an ipad or iphone into word press site. Is there any plugin to achieve this ?. there is a necessity to get back the data in json format and give to developer !!

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say developer, I immediately assume you mean someone trying to add content to the site?

There is a [WordPress app](http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/wordpress/id335703880?mt=8) that you can add your site to, and add Posts, pages, view stats, etc.

Comment: Yes, your assumption is true. Thank you. Let me try @Eric

Comment: How's it going?

Comment: Hi @Eric Holmes , So far i dint used the plugin you suggested , but i am sure, this will be very handy in later stages of my application. currently, i am just fetching static data from database through php code  and using wp-includes/class-phpass.php for validating password(login).